# create an automatic word report using Rmarkdown

Tags: r, report, shiny, r-markdown

I want to create an automatic report in my shiny Application.
I imagine to create a button at the bottom of all pages of my application.
If you click, all graphs and tables are automatically stored in a list of outputs.
At the end of the analyse, you click in a big button, and you generate an automatic word report with all your outputs inside.

I have no idea to do that.

Do you have some examples ?

When I read on the web is a script *.Rmd separated to UI.R and Server.R.
All outputs are inside the *.Rmd .

But I want that the user have the choice to save outputs they wants.

Many thanks for your advices.

Maïna

Comment: "Click in a big button" and everything is done for you. Ah, I wish it was that easy... `R2DOCx`, `R2wd`, `RDCOMClient`,  rmarkdown `output: word_document`, lots of options here. SO doesn't provide a big button to do all the work for you though.

Comment: It is an image :-)
I will program this big button :-) 
thanks cory

Comment: shiny apps have `ui.R` and `server.R`. Rmarkdown documents can be contained in a single file... `yourfilenamehere.Rmd`

Comment: You mean I need to create a unique Rmd file. It will be a mix of and Server.R and ui.R ?

Comment: A rmarkdown document is just a `.Rmd` file. Have you read this yet? http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/

Comment: thanks, 
I said that because I read this link:
https://github.com/rstudio/shiny-examples/tree/master/016-knitr-pdf

Comment: Ah, that is a shiny app, that is able to output a formatted document. You can also have standalone rmarkdown documents that output to word or pdf.

Comment: Isn't the github link you provided what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes ,I think so ! 
But my shiny app is more complex.
I have multiples tables, plots, in multiple tabpanel.
Plots are created using a personal function created by ggplot2 package.
It is not a simple plot()

My Rmd is: 

```{r,  echo = FALSE}
    renderPlot({
      
         data<-filedata()
         
         res.bar<-graphiqueslinetemps(data=data,y=input$varinteret,group=input$varprod,group2=input$vartemps)
         print(res.bar)
          
         
       
     })

 ```

Comment: I imagine you can save the code for all tables/plots using a global string variable in Shiny, and then save that variable to a rmd file, and then `render` it using `rmarkdown`

Comment: Thanks @warmoverflow !  I can generate a report using sweave